# jQuery Accordion Menu Navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, accordion

I'm new to jQuery. I have an accordion menu that I am trying to tweak.  I want the menu to display the correct section expanded depending what page you are on. I have what I think should be working:

```
function initiateMenu() {
var pathname = window.location;

$('#menu ul').hide();
$("a[href$='"+pathname+"']").parent('.sub').show();
$('#menu li a').click(
  function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      return false;
      }

    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
      return false;
      }
    }
  );
}

$(document).ready(function() {initiateMenu();});
```

the HTML for the menu is:

```
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">New Products for 2012</a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/new.php">All New Products</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks.php">Backpacks</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping.php">Camping</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/coolers.php">Coolers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/grills.php">Grills</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/knives.php">Knives</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/lanterns.php">Lanterns</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/sunglasses.php">Sunglasses</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href=#">Backpacks</a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks/">All Backpacks</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks/traditional_backpacks.php">Traditonal Backpacks</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks/messenger_bags.php">Messenger Bags</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href=" <?php echo $lu ; ?>#">Camping &amp; Home</a>
                        <ul class="sub">
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/">All Camping &amp; Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/tables.php">Tables</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/chairs.php">Chairs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/tents_shelters.php">Tents &amp; Shelters</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/airbeds.php">Airbeds</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/sleeping_bags.php">Sleeping Bags</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/accessories.php">Accessories</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                   </ul>
```

The  line `$("a[href$='"+pathname+"']").parent('.sub').show();` was originally `$('#menu ul:first').show();` and worked fine to start the page with the first menu section expanded.  What am I doing wrong and and how can I fix it?

Comment: you could probably try to use [jquery-ui accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) and use the API methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shoudl work, you had some errors in your HTML, and some logic errors in your JS: http://jsfiddle.net/khalifah/TBJYD/

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">New Products for 2012</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/new.php">All New Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks.php">Backpacks</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping.php">Camping</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/coolers.php">Coolers</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/grills.php">Grills</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/knives.php">Knives</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/lanterns.php">Lanterns</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/sunglasses.php">Sunglasses</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Backpacks</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks/">All Backpacks</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks/traditional_backpacks.php">Traditonal Backpacks</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/backpacks/messenger_bags.php">Messenger Bags</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $lu ; ?>#">Camping &amp; Home</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/">All Camping &amp; Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/tables.php">Tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/chairs.php">Chairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/tents_shelters.php">Tents &amp; Shelters</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/airbeds.php">Airbeds</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/sleeping_bags.php">Sleeping Bags</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.jardencustom.com/2012/products/camping/accessories.php">Accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/css">
    function initiateMenu()
    {
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        $( "#menu ul" ).hide();
        $( "#menu a[href='" + pathname + "']" ).parents( ".sub" ).show();
        $( "#menu li a" ).click(function() {
            var checkElement = $( this ).next();

            if ( (checkElement.is("ul") ) && (checkElement.is(":visible")) )
            {
                return false;
            }

            if ( (checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible')) )
            {
                $( "#menu ul:visible" ).slideUp( "normal" );
                checkElement.slideDown( "normal" );
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //$( "#menu" ).accordion({ navigation: true });
        initiateMenu();
    });
</script>
```

Why not use jQuery UI, I think what you want is this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).accordion({ navigation: true });
});
```

This will turn the menu into a jQuery UI accordion menu, then based URL location automatically open it to that menu item.

You'll need jQuery UI though.

Comment: I changed the #sub -> .sub. You shouldn't use id like class. It will catch up to use at some point.

Comment: Thanks! It working and beautiful!  Why did parents work and not parent?  I was only trying to select the one ul not all ul's class=sub?

Answer (score 0):

you should write it like that :

```
$("a[href$='" + pathname + "']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems your pathname is going to look something like:
"/2012/products/grills/propane_grills.php" correct?

After some clarification it seems you may want to try something like this:

```
var pathname = document.location;
$("a[href="+pathname+"]").parent('#sub').show();
```

I don't think location.pathname was giving you the full url.

Okay here is the solution on jsfiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/AMkVT/

Hopefully that helps, I took the html from your existing website and included the jquery.

Comment: Let me clarify, I want to search for the href value of the li under the ul with the id=sub that matches the current url.  Then navigate up to the parent with id=sub, and show that ul in the menu.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer according to your comment. Pretty sure window.location.pathname was not giving you the result you wanted.

Comment: Getting closer all the time, but .show is not showing any ul. Is `.parent('#sub') not selecting the ul like `$('#menu ul:first').show();` does?

Comment: Did you see the jsfiddle? This should be the solution to your problem?